# "On the tournament" vs. "in the tournament"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

What preposition should I use, *in* or *on*? For example:

> 67 people took part **in/on** the tournament.

Comment: *took part in* (is the correct usage, with these extra characters to fill out space)

Answer (score 3):

*In* is the correct preposition to use here, since [*take part **in***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+part) is standard usage as the verb phrase, whereas *take part **on*** is not used.  This [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take%20part%20in,take%20part%20on&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) demonstrates the relative popularities of the two phrases:

[image]

<sup>(If you are unfamiliar with the status of Ngrams as a research tool, see ["official" Ngrams disclaimer](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2469/10041) on meta)</sup>